# Get and object to orbit around another when button is pressed C# XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I have a ship and I want the Ship to follow the mouse, it does that fine and dandy. When forward and backwards are pressed it goes towards and away from the mouse perfectly, but I can not figure out how to make the left and right buttons make the ship circle around the mouse in a clockwise/counterclockwise direction.

I have tried to take the ships location, and the mouse's location, creating a slope, and then getting the perpendicular to that slope, but that doesn't work either.

How can I achieve this? I do not think it needs code, more of an equation, but if there is code, please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generally speaking, we need to see what you've tried and know what 'doesn't work' means. We'll be happy to help you once we have enough information.

Answer (score 2):

You need the parametric form for the equation of a circle. Since you want it centered about the mouse's current location, you need an offset translation. Try something like:

> float radius = 10f; 
>       float shipX;
>       float shipY;
>       float angle = current_angle; // update this to animate
>
> shipX = mouseX + ( radius * Math.Sin(angle));
>   shipY = mouseY + ( radius * Math.Cos(angle));

Comment: What do I do if I want the ship to have a varying Radius from the mouse? Also, How do I get the angle?

Comment: To vary the radius use something like radius = 10.0 + randomNumber. The angle is something you animate based on the timing loop, use something like GameTime mod 360 * Math.Pi.